# Edit Wordpress Previous_post command

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the following code to create previous and next buttons on a wordpress single post.

```
<?php previous_post('&laquo;  %', '', 'yes'); ?>
```

It currently outputs

```
<a href="http://domain.com/?p=6">Name</a>
```

How can I edit this so it outputs

```
<a href="http://domain.com/single.php?p=6">Name</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`previous_post` is now deprecated, you should use [`previous_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link) instead, and then add a filter function to change the URL:

```
function rewrite_previous_post_url($txt) {
    return preg_replace('#\?p=\d+#','single.php$0',$txt);
}
add_filter('previous_post_link','rewrite_previous_post_url');
```